# Search all columns of a spreadsheet for a unique value

Tags: vba, excel

I am struggling with a starting point for my next question. Essentially, I need to be able to search an entire spreadsheet for a unique 13 digit number (which would be unknown so I can't reference it beforehand), find all the references to that number, copy the rows into a new work sheet and then look for the next 13 digit number until all of the different 13 digit references have been copied into new sheets. Now this number may be in column A/B but it also may not, we aren't given the data in set template which is why it needs to search the whole spreadsheet. Can anyone give me an idea as to where to start? I have the basis of a subroutine if I know the numbers beforehand but in this instance, we don't know these numbers just that they are in there. Please help?! This is a VBA solution that I need.
[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t45aq.jpg)

Now the unique number may not always be in Column B which is why the macro needs to be able to identify which column the 13 digit number is in before copying all the rows which relate to it. I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Please provide more information to that problem. The way you've described it is a bit unclear. Could you give an example (fictional data is OK) for us to visualize the problem. Another way is using screenshots (could also be fictional data).

However, from what I understand you, I guess you'd need a VBA solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a generic FindAll function which can serve as a start. You will need to specify a region (eg. .UsedRange) to search and what you are searching for and it will return a range of all the cells that match.

```
Function FindAll(What, _
    Optional SearchWhat As Variant, _
    Optional LookIn, _
    Optional LookAt, _
    Optional SearchOrder, _
    Optional SearchDirection As XlSearchDirection = xlNext, _
    Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False, _
    Optional MatchByte, _
    Optional SearchFormat) As Range

    'LookIn can be xlValues or xlFormulas, _
     LookAt can be xlWhole or xlPart, _
     SearchOrder can be xlByRows or xlByColumns, _
     SearchDirection can be xlNext, xlPrevious, _
     MatchCase, MatchByte, and SearchFormat can be True or False. _
     Before using SearchFormat = True, specify the appropriate settings for the Application.FindFormat _
     object; e.g. Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "General;-General;""-"""

    Dim SrcRange As Range
    If IsMissing(SearchWhat) Then
        Set SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Range Then
        Set SrcRange = IIf(SearchWhat.Cells.Count = 1, SearchWhat.Parent.UsedRange, SearchWhat)
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Worksheet Then
        Set SrcRange = SearchWhat.UsedRange
    Else: SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    End If
    If SrcRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    'get the first matching cell in the range first
    With SrcRange.Areas(SrcRange.Areas.Count)
        Dim FirstCell As Range: Set FirstCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    End With

    Dim CurrRange As Range: Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=FirstCell, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
        SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)

    If Not CurrRange Is Nothing Then
        Set FindAll = CurrRange
        Do
            Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=CurrRange, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
            SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)
            If CurrRange Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            If Application.Intersect(FindAll, CurrRange) Is Nothing Then
                Set FindAll = Application.Union(FindAll, CurrRange)
            Else: Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Function
```